# Dynamic TableViewCell height to fit downloaded image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I was following this answer: [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights) but it lacks 2 things that made me unable to complete it:

1. I set the constraints in the Storyboard prototype cell, not programmatically
2. The image download is done async.

Basically I'm downloading an image using `SDWebImage`, and resizing the `UIImageView`'s height so that it displays the entire image (scaled down, of course). The problems I'm having are commented in the code below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   // dequeue cell using identifier

  [cell.pictureView sd_setImageWithUrl:myUrl completed:^( ... block ...) {

       // This code will scale down the UIImage to the UIImageView's width maitaining
       // its aspect ratio, and also will resize the UIImageView's to match the scaled-down UIImage's height

       if(image != nil) {
         CGSize imageSize = [image size];
         CGSize imageViewSize = CGSizeMake(280.0, 100.0);

         CGFloat correctHeight = (imageViewSize.width / imageSize.width) * imageSize.height;

         [[cell pictureView] setFrame:CGRectMake([[cell pictureView] frame].origin.x,
                                                  [[cell pictureView] frame].origin.y,
                                                  CGRectGetWidth([[cell pictureView] bounds]),
                                                  correctHeight)];

           // At this point, the subviews are all set. Since this happens async, what method do I call to re-calculate this row's height.

  }];


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static int defaultHeight = 230;

    // Get's the offscreen cell used only for calculation purposes
    WKZEventsCell *cell = [[self offscreenCells] objectForKey:CellIdentifier];
    if(!cell) {

        // HOW DO I GET A REFERENCE TO A PROTOTYPED CELL INSIDE THE STORYBOARD??? 
        // note that calling dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier will cause a memory leak      

        cell = ??????
        [[self offscreenCells] setObject:cell forKey:CellIdentifier];
    }

    WKZEvent *event = [[self eventList] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell titleLabel] setText:[event title]];
    [[cell placeLabel] setText:[event title]];
    [[cell pictureView] setImage:image];


    // Even tho this should be in memory cache right now, I'm pretty sure this call is still asynchronous, so this might make the whole thing wont work.
    [cell.pictureView sd_setImageWithUrl:myUrl


    // THIS METHODS ARE COMMENTED BECAUSE MY CONSTRAINTS ARE SET IN STORYBOARD, BUT NOT SURE IF I'M RIGHT AT THIS ONE
    //[cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    //[cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

    // I DONT HAVE A MULTILINE LABEL SO I DONT CALL THIS. NOT SURE ABOUT THIS ONE EITHER
    //cell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(cell.bounds));

    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGFloat height = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

    height += 1;

    NSLog(@"%f", height);

    return height;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Storyboard:**

- Add a new cell to your table view
- Add a new image view to the cell
- Optionally set a placeholder image for the image view
- Make cell's constraints describe its height unambiguously

Be sure to leave *Row Height* of the cell set to *Default*

**Code:**

Make the table view to self-size cells:

```
var tableview: UITableView {
    didSet {
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    }
}
```

At runtime, start loading the image asynchronously as soon as possible.

When downloaded, load the image to the image view and execute:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```